# Is it possible to replace the flashlight LED on an ESP32-CAM board with an infrared LED?

Tags: led, infrared, esp32cam

I'm looking for a way to modify an ESP32-CAM board, specifically its built-in flashlight LED.

I want desolder the white LED and replace it with an IR LED. Is that possible?

Also, what should I notice before I start modifying?

[image: esp32cam dev board]

Comment: Most probably yes. The Vf will be lower on an IR LED so you might want to increase the series resistance (if any) to compensate. Do you have schematic?

Comment: @winny I don't have schematic but I have picture of esp32cam development board. It's common board in market. That board is my plan to modify. I updated my question to insert picture.

Comment: I still didn't find SMD version of infrared LED in market, is that thing really exist?

Comment: Camera sensor may have IR filter so the modification may be useless.

Comment: More than 1000 to choose from on Digikey: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/led-emitters-infrared-uv-visible/94?s=N4IgjCBcoCwAxVAYygFwE4FcCmAaEA9lANogBMAnHBQKw0j6VgDsAzGQ%2BRWe855WRgwIjCqxgA2PvlZwWcABwgAuvgAOqKCADKGAJYA7AOYgAvqcYkQASVQACADbYAJitNA

Comment: @user263983 I just test esp32 camera to capture led from remote tv, It shown purple color. That's mean no IR filter in ESP 32 camera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

The schematic of the ESP32-CAM can be found [here](https://github.com/SeeedDocument/forum_doc/blob/master/reg/ESP32_CAM_V1.6.pdf) and [here](https://oshwlab.com/ManishRajput/esp32-cam). The last link also has the PCB design.

This is the bit that shows the flash LED's connections:

[image: Flash LED connection]
*<sup>Source: see links above.</sup>*

If you replace the LED with another one, you will have to change this part of the circuit to accommodate the new LED's V<sub>f</sub> and current.

Make sure you pick an IR LED that can be powered by this (modified) circuit (voltage, current, thermal), and that doesn't have a wavelength that is blocked by the camera's IR filter (if any).

Note that several version of this camera board may exist, so YMMV.